# Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tl')

Tags: exceljs

var base64Image="data:image/png;base64,"+base64String;

```
// Create a new Excel workbook and worksheet
const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Images');
// console.log(base64Image.substring(0, 50));
base64Image=base64Image.toString();
// console.log(base64Image);

// Add column headers
worksheet.addRow(['Image']);

// Insert images into the worksheet
const image1 = worksheet.addImage({
  base64: base64Image,
  extension: '.png',
});
// worksheet.addImage(image1, 'B2:D6');
worksheet.addImage(image1, {
  tl: { col: 1.5, row: 1.5 },
  br: { col: 3.5, row: 5.5 },
});

// Save the Excel file
const excelFilePath = './images.xlsx';
workbook.xlsx.writeFile(excelFilePath)
```

I want to add multiple images and tables in excel using exceljs in node or angular

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo for adding table and image (from the file)

#### Save as `output.js`

```js
const Excel = require('exceljs');

const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Sample")

// add a table to a sheet
worksheet.addTable({
    name: 'Dam',
    ref: 'A1',
    headerRow: true,
    totalsRow: true,
    columns: [
        { name: 'Product', totalsRowLabel: 'Totals:', filterButton: false },
        { name: 'Qtr1', totalsRowFunction: 'sum', filterButton: false },
        { name: 'Qtr2', totalsRowFunction: 'sum', filterButton: false },
        { name: 'Qtr3', totalsRowFunction: 'sum', filterButton: false },
        { name: 'Qtr4', totalsRowFunction: 'sum', filterButton: false, width: 20 },
    ],
    rows: [
        ["Frames", 5000, 7000, 6544, 4377],
        ["Saddles", 400, 323, 276, 651],
        ["Brake levers", 12000, 8766, 8456, 9812],
        ["Chains", 1550, 1088, 692, 853],
        ["Mirrors", 225, 600, 923, 544],
        ["Spokes", 6005, 7634, 4589, 8765]
    ],
});

const row = worksheet.getRow(11);
row.height = 100;

const column = worksheet.getColumn(5);
column.width = 200/8;

imageData = { image_file_name: "2t.png"};
const imageId = workbook.addImage({
    filename: `./images/${imageData['image_file_name']}`,
    extension: 'png',
});

worksheet.addImage(
    imageId,
    'E11:E11',
    {
        width: 20,
        height: 10
    }
);

const fileName = './output.xlsx';
workbook.xlsx
    .writeFile(fileName)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('file created');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
```

#### Install dependency

```
npm install exceljs
```

File tree
The `t2.png` located under `images` directory.

[image]

#### Run it

```
node output.js
```

#### Result

[image]

#### References

[How to add table in exceljs for angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011852/how-to-add-table-in-exceljs-for-angular)

[ExcelJS doesn't add image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931079/exceljs-doesnt-add-image)