# How to add a complex formula in exceljs - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, xlsx, exceljs

I'm currently working on a project that requires to export data in multiple xlsx sheets. In one of them, I need to add formula in cells that verified some conditions before adding some data from the first sheet. Here is one of them:

```
Ref !== null ? worksheet2.getCell('D2').value ={ formula: `IF('dataSheet'!${Ref.address}<>"";'dataSheet'!${Ref.address};"")`, result:Ref.value} : worksheet2.getCell('D2').value = '';
```

Ref here is a cell in the first sheet containing the "ref" label.

The problem with this formula (or any "IF" formula) is that I get this error when I open the excel document: `We found a problem with some content in test.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.`

And when I do, it recovers the whole document except all of the IF formulas. I also have some VLOOKUP formula that don't work either.

Simple formula such as A1+A2 works but that's basically it.

I also tested other common formula like SUM or AVERAGE, but they did not work either. I tried with or without an "=" before the formula with no success. I tried simple formula such as `formula: '=IF(A1=0;10;0)'` with no success. I read that you sometime need to add the result, and as you can see in the first part, it did not work.

I also tried another package, XLSX with a IF and a SUM formula but the same problem appears all over again.

Last but not least, as I work in a french company all the formula are written in french so IF is SI.. I first though it could be a miscommunication between the exceljs language use and the one in Excel options but even after changing it and formula to english, it still shows me the same message.

Comment: can you make a picture with real example cross over between sheet?
One cell shows real data next cell show texted formula. It will help understand your question. SUM is possible by `exceljs` in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857453/error-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-tl/76891786#76891786)

Comment: I can't really show it beacuse it is not generated. The part where I should have my formula is blank and in the datasheet I have this: https://imgur.com/a/8iAxWLd

In JavaScript, Ref is a let that retrieve the Cell next to the one call "ref". This is to ensure I always use the good address even when the place of each category move. (There is options to generate or not certains part).

Comment: My request is like this image. It has just what kind of formula by manual enter. it will help how to create formula by `exceljs`.  In datasheet, [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dltb7.png). In formula sheet, [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkRFo.png)

Comment: Ok my bad, here is the formula: https://imgur.com/a/BSUiZhd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will work.

```js
worksheet.getCell('D2').value = { formula: 'IF(datasheet!A1<>"",datasheet!B1,"")'};
```

Some formula example in [here](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#formula-value)

This `demo.js` will create `test.xls`

```js
const Excel = require('exceljs');

const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

const data_sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("datasheet")
const formula_sheet = workbook.addWorksheet("formula")


// set data_sheet data
data_sheet.getCell('A1').value = 'ref';

data_sheet.getCell('B1').value = 1;

// set formula data
formula_sheet.getCell('A1').value = 2;
formula_sheet.getCell('A2').value = 3;
formula_sheet.getCell('A3').value = { formula: 'SUM(A1,A2)'};

formula_sheet.getCell('D2').value = { formula: 'IF(datasheet!A1<>"",datasheet!B1,"")'};

const fileName = './test.xlsx';
workbook.xlsx
    .writeFile(fileName)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('file created');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
```

In `datasheet`,

[image]

In `formula`

[image]

The D2 cell's formula will create

```
=IF(datasheet!A1<>"",datasheet!B1,"")
```

And display

```
1
```

due to `datasheet`'s `A1` is `ref` and `B1` is 1.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, it was the " ; " in formula that was wrong. In Excel, the coma is replace by " ; " so I was using this one until I test your code. 
I don't have the reputation to mark this answer as useful but it was. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem, you can accept my answer if click up arrow in my answer. It will give me 15 points even if you are 1 point. It will make me happy.